# How to distinguish function from bash_profile is running at start or called by user later?

Tags: bash, interactive

I am writing a function in bash_profile that needs to be silence when first load by bash at start(eg. each time in a new xterminal), and then be verbose if user calls it later within that bash.

I need the function to run when bash starts and also run upon user's request.

Is there a way to distinguish this ?

I tried `"$PS1"` and `"$-"`, both are interactive.

Sorry for my poor English, I mean a function to create a per user memdisk for cache. It should be created once a interactive login, thus I put it into `~/.profile`. It also should be switch off and on by user, so the function should be verbose when user called it later.

During login, it should be silence, and when user try to switch, it must be verbose.

For short, I need sth. like `swap on` to be silence when user login, but be verbose when user type it later.

Comment: Are you calling the function from `~/.bash_profile`, or just having its definition there?

Comment: Completely not understandable if the one below is the answer.... you say "I am writing a function in bash_profile that needs to be silenced when first load by bash at start"

Comment: I need both to run it within `~/.bash_profile` and to run it later upon user's request. The function need to be executed in both situations.

Comment: OK. I should not say unrelated things like silence/verbose here. Please read the title. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40281964/

Answer (score -1):

Heard from others:

Two ways to are to pass an argument, or to check the environment.

---

I just find a way to use `etime` of `$$`.

```
setit() {
    BashRun=$(ps -p "$$" -o etime=|tr '-' ':'|awk -F: '{total=0;m=1;} {for (i=0;i<NF;i++) {total+=$(NF-i)*m;m*=i>=2?24:60}} {print total}')
    ... ...
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        if [ $BashRun -gt 1 ]; then
            echo "It has already been set !"
        fi
    fi
}
```

Comment: Why simply setup an environment variable is not enough?