# How to make a bash_profile function acts different running within bash_profile or later called by user?

Tags: function, bash

I mean, in `~/.profile`, a function `doit` will say `Welcome` when user login, but say other words when user execute `doit` later.

```
doit() {
    if some_test_here; then
        echo "Running within ~/.profile. Welcome."
    else
        echo "Called by user."
    fi
}

doit
```

I think `~/.profile` is better on Mac for `~/.bash_profile` on Linux. So I use `~/.profile` as example.

Comment: `.profile` should be used for commands that could be used by *any* POSIX shell. `bash` will use `.profile` if neither `.bash_profile` or `.bash_login` exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways to are to pass an argument, or to check the environment.

---

Use an argument that is only used by the call in `.profile`.

```
doit () {
    if [ "${1:-onlogin}" -eq onlogin ]; then
        echo "Running from .profile"
    else
        echo "Called by user"
    fi
}

doit onlogin  # from .profile
doit          # ordinary call
```

---

Check the environment for a variable set by .profile

```
doit () {
  if [ "${_onlogin}" ]; then
    echo "Running from .profile"
  else
    echo "Called by user"
  fi
}

onlogin=1 doit    # from .profile; value can be any non-empty string
doit              # ordinary call
```

Comment: I think your comment on the question should also be a part of the answer, because this answer could fail if the criteria you mentioned isn't satisfied.

Comment: How so? `doit` is POSIX-compliant.

Comment: I'm confused, you said ` bash will use .profile if neither .bash_profile or .bash_login exists.` - so there's a probability that .profile might not be sourced?

Comment: If that's the case, this code goes in the file that *does* get used. I was just commenting on the assertion that `.profile` is somehow "better" than `.bash_profile`. Neither is better than the other; they are just used in different situations.